# Cannot connect to HDP sandbox in docker

Tags: hortonworks-sandbox

I have successfully started hortonworks sandbox container in my docker in my macbook. The guide said to connect to sandbox via this command:

`ssh -p 2222 root@localhost`

But it gives me

`ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused`

Then I tried

`ssh -p 22 root@localhost`

It asks me the password (instead of prompting me to change my password as the guide says).  I tried to input "hadoop" as password but it won't let me in.  I tried "root", still the same.  I tried to login using my laptop password, still cannot login.

How should I be able to connect to sandbox container?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should exec into the container using. hortonworkssandbox is the container name when you launched it.

```
docker exec -it hortonworkssandbox /bin/bash
```

Comment: it worked well for me, but I had to put the container ID instead of name. I have docker on macOS

Answer (score 1):

If you `ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 22` you will be in Centos 
If you `ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 2222` you will be connected to the sandbox 
for localhost connection replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with root@localhost.

run `ps -ef | grep container-ip` in order to get container ip

now `ssh root@container ip` and then `ambari-admin-password-reset`
probabaly you will be able to set password.

For virtual box you can follow below approach:

Goto terminal of your sandbox in oracle virtualBox --> Press  --> enter username - root --> enter password - hadoop --> it will ask you to set new password --> set new password --> then try to login via putty using new credentials

Comment: so you have to connect over the hdp proxy container that redirects you to the hdp main container, I could verify this, ifconfig shows the HDP sanbdox IP in the end, but you have to connect over the HDP proxy IP.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of root login, try to use port: 2200

**Note**: This port is correct only if you have HDP (sandbox) which is running as VirtualBox VM. In the case of docker this info is useless.

Comment: Sorry. This port is correct only if you have HDP (sandbox) which is running as VirtualBox VM. In the case of docker this info is useless.